# How to fix Fresh Ubuntu minimal server missing locale?

Tags: system-installation, locale, ubuntu-minimal

I just ordered plain Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS min on vServer VX11 from Hetzner.de and after `apt-get update` I get this error

```
Fetched 65.6 MB in 3s (20.1 MB/s)      
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "et_EE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
```

This locale error happens with many commands. How to remove this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal and perform this commands:

```
sudo locale-gen et_EE et_EE.UTF-8 en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```